# Deployment file error but can not find where issued from

Tags: kubernetes, deployment

I hope people can help to point out where is the issue from my deployment file, when i deploy i get error below
Thanks for your help

```
"Deployment.apps "my-app" is invalid: [spec.template.spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[0].name: Not found: "audioSources", spec.template.spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[1].name: Not found: "authors", spec.template.spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[2].name: Not found: "covers"]"
```

here is my deployment file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: my-app
  name: my-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: myname/myimage
        name: my-app
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
        volumeMounts:
        - name: audioSources
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html/audioSources
        - name: authors
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html/authors
        - name: covers
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html/covers
  volumes:
    - name: audioSources
      hostPath:
        path: /home/websites/audioSources
    - name: authors
      hostPath:
        path: /home/websites/authors
    - name: covers
      hostPath:
        path: /home/websites/covers
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's due to the **indentation** error in your YAML file

**Volume** should be under the **spec** section

Example **YAML** i am using

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: hello-app
  name: hello-app
  namespace: default
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-app
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: hello-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /etc/cert/
            name: foo
          - mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d
            name: nginxconf
            readOnly: true
      - image: gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: hello-app
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30 
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 256
          name: nginxthroughpass
          optional: false
        name: nginxconf
      - name: foo
        secret:
          defaultMode: 420
          items:
          - key: tls.crt
            path: tls.crt
          - key: tls.key
            path: tls.key
          secretName: nginx-prod
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fixed deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: my-app
  name: my-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: myname/myimage
        name: my-app
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
        volumeMounts:
        - name: audio-sources
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html/audioSources
        - name: authors
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html/authors
        - name: covers
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html/covers
      volumes:
      - name: audio-sources
        hostPath:
          path: /home/websites/audioSources
      - name: authors
        hostPath:
          path: /home/websites/authors
      - name: covers
        hostPath:
          path: /home/websites/covers
```

1. Volumes should be under `spec`,same level as `containers`.
2. Also, name of `audioSource` is changed to `audio-source`.